# How to Set, Use iOS 10.2 Parental Controls on iPhone 7 Plus

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to be safe from my child use my iPhone, what i have to do? To restrict my device running on iOS 10.2?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to restrict?

You can restrict apps:

Settings > General > Restrictions > Select app.

You can restrict websites, content:

Settings > General > Restrictions > Allowed content.

You can set a Password:

Settings > Touch ID & Passcode.

Or you can use third part apps that block specific content and apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the learning mode to keep your child within a specific app, like a puzzle or game that you allow it to play.

Settings > General > Accesibility > Learning

Enable Guided access.
Configure a passcode
Optionally configure Time limits.

Now open the app your kid wants to use/play, triple-click the home button
- select the area that may be clickable
- select the hardware buttons that are allowed (volume is a good one :))
- click start.

You kid can now only use that specific app, without leaving it.

To exit this mode, just triple-click home and enter the configured passcode.

I use this all the time with my kids (also on iPad).

Cheers